# Checking nearest similarity in video using image data set

Tags: image, opencv, video, dataset, comparison

I'm trying to detect eye glows for an app to use for medical purposes. Is there a way or an approach I can use to compare the region of interest detecting the eye glow to a series of images of eye glow that I have? More likely comparing via color. But since eye glow is not a general color like red, blue, green, yellow I don't know how to compare it and show a similarity percentage for about 80% and up. Thank you.

I already read a lot of similar topics here on StackOverflow. I also did quite some Googling. Sadly I couldn't come up with a satisfieng answer.

Old question put on hold:

Does OpenCV support the comparison of video and image data set, returning some value (maybe a percentage) that indicates similarity? I'm trying to create an app that detects the eye glow and compare it in a data set of images. More likely I am studying if a CBIR(Content based image retrieval) like feature can be applied but the input is the pupil from a real time video.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not a satisfying answer to create a CBIR.

Ok, the first answer is: OpenCV doesn't have any CBIR system.

The steps to build a good CBIR are:

1. Identify your ROI in your image. So imagine you've got a camera and you're having many images. You are interested maybe in the whole image, or in a piece of it. That piece is your ROI. To detect a ROI you have to know what you want to *describe*. Once you know what you want, you need to trigger it by a detector, tracker. Take a look to [Haar Cascade](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/objdetect/doc/cascade_classification.html) implementations to do it, or [Template Matching](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html) for example.
2. Once you've got your ROI, you need to describe it. Are you looking for colour searchs? maybe edges? You will have to describe your image with some vector, word, whatever. Take a look to these topics: [one](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/features2d/doc/feature_detection_and_description.html), [two](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/ocl/doc/feature_detection_and_description.html) and if you keep researching you'll get many more :)
3. The process of detecting and describing is not only when you want to know something. You need to write a database of what you want to detect, and apply the same process to your image. You'll need to take distances. For example for colours you can use [delta E](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_difference), and for any vectors you can use just norm-2 for example.
4. If this is not enough, you'll maybe need a classification system working with machine learning. What about using [Caffe](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/) ?

I hope you can find your path to make it ;).

Comment: Thank you for the answer @RafaelRuiz. I'm currently new in using opencv. I was able to detect eye region using haar cascade classifier. And detect the pupil using hough circles. Is color detection via histogram can be use to compare in an image data set and will it gives me if it is close similar. Maybe around 90%. Don't know if this comment is acceptable. Sorry.

Comment: You can use an histogram, you can divide into several segments. More segments, more defined it is, but less accuracy depending of what you want to detect. Bear in mind that if you use histograms, you're tracking method will be affected by light conditions normally.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'll try using it.